# Error loading texture ../../widgets/cityCC0.mpg

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to get myself around Kivy framework, I'm also kind of new to Python, so I really can't solve this. But basically I'm trying the examples and the Kivy catalog one is not working and I'm geetting this on the terminal. I'm on macOS 10.14.4 using Python3.7.

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-12.8.38'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [VideoGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.10.4.0
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: gstplayer
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture ../../widgets/cityCC0.mpg
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/diogo/Desktop/repos/kivy/examples/demo/kivycatalog/main.py", line 192, in <module>
     KivyCatalogApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 337, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 581, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/video.py", line 183, in _do_video_load
     self._video = CoreVideo(filename=filename, **self.options)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py", line 56, in __init__
     super(VideoGstplayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 84, in __init__
     self.filename = kwargs.get('filename')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 116, in <lambda>
     lambda self, x: self._set_filename(x),
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/video/__init__.py", line 113, in _set_filename
     self.load()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/video/video_gstplayer.py", line 68, in load
     self.player.load()
   File "kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load
 kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `gstreamer` directory from `kivy/lib`.

- Change directory to Kivy folder, e.g. `cd usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lib`
- Remove gstreamer, `rm -R gstreamer`
- Rerun the app